# Connecting to MySQL through VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I would like to know if there's a way to take out data from MySQL database without using the explicit string which contain database's username and password

```
connection = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;userid=root;pwd=pass")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, MySql has two modes to allow this:

1. Certificate-based authentication (similar to ssh, but not sure what this looks like from an app)
2. Windows/Integrated authentication (via plug-in)

Here's an example of that last option via [Connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

> **Use Windows authentication**
>
> ```
> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;IntegratedSecurity=yes;Uid=auth_windows;
> ```
>
> This option is available from Connector/NET version 6.4.4
>
> The Windows Native Authentication Plugin must be installed for this to work.

.Net also has built-in support for encrypting sections of a config file, such that you can store this in a safe way.